# How to use jQuery Ajax to fetch the data from MS-SQl database?

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm developing an Event Calendar in PHP, saving the data in MS-SQL.

I was successful in sending the data to the database, however, I'm not able to fetch the data from it.

Here's what I've done so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    events: "all_events.php",
    displayEventTime: false,
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
      if (event.allDay === 'true') {
        event.allDay = true;
      } else {
        event.allDay = false;
      }
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      var title = prompt('Event Detail:');
      if (title) {
        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

        $.ajax({
          url: 'add_event.php',
          data: 'title=' + title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end,
          type: "POST",
          success: function(data) {
            displayMessage("Added Successfully");
          }
        });
        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
          title: title,
          start: start,
          end: end,
          allDay: allDay
        }, true);
      }
      calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    }
  });
});
```

all_events.php

```html
<?php
  require_once("connection.php");
  $conn = DB::databaseConnection();
  $json = array();
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY id";
  $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $result->bindParam(':id', $id);
  $alldata = array();
  while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    array_push($alldata, $row);
  }
  echo json_encode($alldata);
?>
```

I'm just getting a '[]' in the console. No other error and the calendar is blank, it is not displaying any data from the database.

Comment: "I'm just getting a '[]' in the console"...in the console where, exactly? I see no console.log commands in your code (and it's unclear where you'd put one anyway). Do you mean in the Network view of the Response to your call to all_events.php? That would make some sense.

Comment: Anyway, as far as I can see, in your PHP `$result->bindParam(':id', $id);` makes no sense because a) you don't have a PHP variable called $id and b) you don't have a parameter called `:id` in your SQL statement. What did you think the purpose of this line was? More than likely this should be causing an error (or at least a warning) to occur in your PHP code (unless you have suppressed them all for some reason).

Comment: Oh yes. I meant in the Network view of the Response.

Comment: Agreed that's a mistake, but I don't think that's the reason for the data not being fetched from the database

Comment: Why not? If PHP and/or SQL is crashing, then clearly it would prevent any data being retrieved. And if you're suppressing errors, then you could easily end up with a blank array.

Comment: Even after removing that line off, the response is still the same

Comment: Of course the other obvious reason for not having any results is...not having any results. Check that the database table contains rows, and that you're connecting to the right copy of the database. From the code and info shown, it's hard to see what else the problem would be, to be honest.

Comment: Yes the connection and the sql statement is all correct. I've double checked and my piece of code for insert is working fine.

Comment: Oh actually, I just noticed: you never execute your query.... (again you must be suppressing errors/warnings, which is really bad practice, otherwise this should cause your code to complain when it tries to loop through $result. This particular incident is an excellent lesson in why suppressing everything is a bad idea. Let the code fail, and log the errors/warnings etc, then you can use them to debug.)

Comment: As in? Can you please explain?

Comment: Have you used PDO before? I mean that you forgot the `execute()` command. In your case because you named your statement object as `$result`, you would need to write `$result->execute();` after the call to `prepare()`.

Comment: Oh yes. That's where I had made a mistake. Thank yo so much. Please put it as an answer :)

Comment: TBH it's so trivial it's barely worth it. It's just an oversight (one which can be easily resolved by consulting one of the many tutorials, documentation pages, previous questions etc etc online which show how to use PDO correctly.). IMO the question could just be deleted.